# Shuffling a deck of cards once versus shuffling at the time of draw

Tags: probability, random

I was recently looking at some Javascript for a Gloomhaven card drawing application (https://www.gloomhaven-deck.com), and I noticed that the author shuffles the modifier deck by choosing a random card out of the deck at the time that the card is drawn, rather than shuffling the cards a single time to create a "shuffled" deck.

My question is whether this method of shuffling (choosing a random card at the time of drawing) is functionally any different from a standard one-time shuffle (such as Fisher-Yates) where you create the shuffled deck and pull cards off of the top one at a time. I can't think of any way this would be any less robust.

Comment: It sounds like the author is in effect doing the Fisher-Yates shuffle, but just one step at a time: each time you draw a card, it picks one at random from what remains in the (ordered) deck. Unless you wind up drawing every single card in the deck, doing a complete Fisher-Yates shuffle can involve a lot of unnecessary computation.

Comment: They are the same. Barry Cipra has explained it well. Both methods create an ordering where all orderings are equally likely, one predetermines the ordering by shuffling outright. The other determines the order as you go.